# Efficient way to find the number of clusters in a Pytorch tensor

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to find an efficient way to estimate the number of clusters in a tensor (`my_tensor`). The issue is that I need to do this many times, and my tensor is changing. I have access to a GPU if that helps.

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
my_tensor = torch.rand(4096,4096).to(device)
for i in range(10000):
    new_tensor = neural_network(my_tensor) # neural_network is some function
    number_of_clusters = find_number_of_clusters(new_tensor) # "find_number_of_clusters" is what I'm looking for
    my_tensor = new_tensor
```

I know there isn't an exact number of clusters in a tensor usually, hence I mostly need an estimate that is efficient. Note that I don't have labels.